# Using jQuery for user registration form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a website for learning/exercise but I'm stuck at user registration validation. There's no error message and nothing happens.

Here is a [JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/3nodfL17/).

Also I tried:

```
if(user_name.length < 3 && user_name!=="")
```

and

```
if(user_name.length < 3)
```

Code snippet:

```js
var user_name = $('#username').val();

$('#username').on('keyup',function(){
  if(user_name.length < 3 && user_name!=""){
    $('#username-info').html('Username must be at least 3 characters.');
  }
  else if(user_name.length > 3){
    $('#username_info').html('No problem');
  }
});
```

```css
#username-info {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="username">
<p id="username-info"></p>
```

Comment: first of all, I think you select not correct element for `keyup` event. I think it should be  `$('#username')` instead of `$('#username_info')` cause you are typing in textBox and not in `p` element

Comment: Still nothing happens. Also I was writing code in another language after translating it to English I wrote it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `keyup` functions need to trigger on the input field.

The `keyup` functions updates the `username` (else it will be the same).

```
$('#username').on('keyup',function(){
    var user_name = $('#username').val();
  if(user_name.length < 3 && user_name!=""){
    $('#username-info').html('Username must be at least 3 characters.');
  }
  else if(user_name.length >= 3){
    $('#username-info').html('No problem');
  }
});
```

Comment: Test your snippet with the given HTML, and you will see that is still not working correctly.

Comment: There was a typo after the else if #username_info -> #username-info

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `user_name` is declared once at the start of your script, so it will never be updated.

Then, you attached a `keyup` event handler on `<p#username-info>`, not `<input#username>`, so when you input something into it, nothing will be triggered.

So, you need to update `user_name` at each input into `<input#username>`.

```js
// Here, you need to attach the event handler of #username, not #username-info.
$('#username').on('keyup', function() {
  // And here, you get the value of your input.
  let user_name = $('#username').val();
  // let user_name = $(this).val(); works too.

  // Writing "(user_name)" in a condition is the same as "(user_name !== '')".
  if (user_name && user_name.length < 3) {
    $('#username-info').html('Username must be at least 3 characters.');
  } else if (user_name.length >= 3) {
    // You wrote "#username_info" instead of "#username-info" here.
    $('#username-info').html('No problem');
  }
});
```

```css
#username-info {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="username">
<p id="username-info">
</p>
```

Comment: Error says `at least 3 characters`, while i add 3 characters it still shows an error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have just put wrong ids AND your variable `user_name` is only initialized one time on start, so its value is always empty.

```js
$('#username').on('keyup', function() {
  var user_name = $(this).val();
  if (user_name.length < 3 && user_name != "") {
    $('#username-info').html('Username must be at least 3 characters.');
  } else if (user_name.length > 3) {
    $('#username-info').html('No problem');
  }
});
```

```css
#username-info {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="username">
<p id="username-info">
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a lot of typos in your script and you looked for the paragraph on key up not your input field.

```
var user_name = "";
$('#username').on('keyup',function(){
   user_name = $('#username').val();

  if(user_name.length <= 3 && user_name!=""){
    $('#username-info').html('Username must be at least 3 characters.');
  }
  else if(user_name.length > 3){
    $('#username-info').html('No problem');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use your code as reference and made some changes in it for better output.

You can try this, here i am changing color code as well for the error message so you will get better result.

```js
$('#username').on('keyup',function(){
    var user_name = $('#username').val();
 if(user_name.length < 3 && user_name != ""){
     $('#username-info').html('Username must be at least 3 characters.');
  $('#username-info').addClass('username-info');
  $('#username-info').removeClass('username-info-2');
 }
 else if(user_name.length >= 3){
  $('#username-info').html('No problem');
  $('#username-info').addClass('username-info-2');
  $('#username-info').removeClass('username-info');
 }
});
```

```css
.username-info {
  color: red;
  }
.username-info-2 {
  color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="username">

<p id="username-info"></p>
```